# C# : Presentation save not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, powerpoint, add-in

I am trying to save, modified changes in an existing powerpoint file loaded from disk. i was successfully able to open the file.
While tried to save edited (already existing) powerpoint file using saveas method, exception is observed.

```
private void adxPowerPointAppEvents1_PresentationBeforeSave(object sender, ADXHostBeforeActionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PowerPoint.Presentation pre = e.HostObject as 
            PowerPoint.Presentation;

            // cancel this operation
            e.Cancel = true;

            //save
            pre.SaveAs(pre.Name, 
    PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault,Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
            MessageBox.Show("you will not see me due to exception");

     }    
     catch(Exception e){}
```

}

When code is executed, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q79Qp.png)

The approach used in msword and msexcel were not working.

If there would be either approach to save the edited file, kindly help me ..

Comment: You have not check if theas operator has returned null. I am not sure if this will cause your exception but I guess it is a good ide to change this.

Comment: SaveAs() call throws exception..(Details were attached)

Comment: Can you talk us through why your add-in cancels the save (`e.Cancel = true`) and then on the very next line calls `SaveAs` itself? Also see http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-321219.html .

Comment: Actually when i type long paragraph, we save the file frequently in the middle right?? for every save event, the dialog box appears.. where we have to manually press cancel.. instead of that obj.cancel is set as true and saveas() is called

Comment: @mjwills Yes.. i already checked that link.. but that solution finds to be more unclear and also not any useful info could be extracted pertaining to this issue...
I feel that solution needs quite improvement.

Comment: @mjwills reply for comment 3..
If we did not cancel save event(e.cancel =true) , then on save() we would find infinite recursive call...ie save() will again and again call Presentation_save event handler.. so to get rid of that we cancel save event

Answer (score 0):

Got solution for this problem...
Like in word, excel we can't make save() operation... Powerpoint throws an exception if we call save or saveas from the same event handler(function).Accordingly, you must call SaveAs outside of that event handler, after PowerPoint invokes it.

```
private void adxPowerPointAppEvents_PresentationBeforeSave(object sender, ADXHostBeforeActionEventArgs e)
        {
            PowerPoint.Presentation pre = e.HostObject as PowerPoint.Presentation;
            try
            {

                if (pre.Saved == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;

                    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(pre.FullName);
                    IntPtr parameter = (IntPtr)handle;


                    this.SendMessage(MESSAGE_SAVE_PPT, parameter, IntPtr.Zero);
                    pre.Saved = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Info("Exception while saving powerpoint : " + ex.StackTrace);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
                return;
        }

private void AddinModule_OnSavePowerPointMessage(object sender, AddinExpress.MSO.ADXSendMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Message == MESSAGE_SAVE_PPT)
            {
                PowerPoint.Presentation ppPre = null;
                try
                {
                    GCHandle handle = (GCHandle)e.WParam;
                    String fullName = (handle.Target as String);

                    ppPre = PowerPointApp.Presentations[fullName];
                    if (ppPre != null)
                    {
                        ppPre.Saved = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                        //ppPre.SaveAs(ppPre.FullName, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
                        ppPre.Save();


                        Log.Info("Value of pre.name " + ppPre.Name);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exSavePpt)
                {
                    Log.Info("Exception while saving powerpoint : " + exSavePpt.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
```

Actually, in AddinModule_OnSavePowerPointMessage(), We should not pass COM objects which would create com exception. So instead that we should pass presentation name(ppt.fullname) and create com reference pointing to same object in the second method. So, without any trouble now i could save ppt files...